# Why do Spring Framework jpetstore sample has several dependencies issues?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am exploring the Spring Framework examples. I have checked them out from [here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/).

Yet, when I open the jpetstore example in NetBeans, it mentions several missing or unresolved maven dependencies:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.aop.AfterReturningAdvice;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.ServletEndpointSupport;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
...
```

When I ask NetBeans to find them, it can't find them. What is causing this issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see, this PetStore example project depends on some SNAPSHOT versions of Spring artifacts that are unavailable now. Spring 3.0.0 is already released, so change `<spring.version>3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>` property to `<spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>` and should be OK. I don't have NetBeans to check this out, but at least console build with `mvn clean package` works now.